# Receiving from Twitter streaming API on iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, twitter, streaming, twitter-streaming-api

I'm unsure of how to work with the Twitter streaming API on iOS. Do I need to do something special, as I'm expecting multiple responses? I tried the following, but instead of treating it as a stream, expecting multiple responses, it returns the data through it's delegate in chunks. I guess a different definition of streaming?

```
    let request = Twitter.sharedInstance().APIClient.URLRequestWithMethod(
        "GET",
        URL: "https://userstream.twitter.com/1.1/user.json",
        parameters: parameters,
        error: &error)

    self.urlConnection = NSURLConnection(request: request, delegate: self, startImmediately: false)
    self.urlConnection!.start()
```